# Redirect to error page in non controller class / request method..?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am writing a Spring Boot application, in one of my controllers I have the following mapping:

```
@PostMapping("/")
public String doSomething(  ) 
{   
    Foo bar = new Foo();
    bar.doSomething();
    return "/Complete";
}
```

And also another mapping for mappings in a Exception handling class:

```
@PostMapping("/error")
public ModelAndView doSomething( String error ) 
{   
    // Handle error here..
}
```

So in the class bar *Which is a not a controller* is there a way to redirect to the /error mapping passing down an error.. I ask this as it saves me have to constantly throw exceptions up call stacks / which catches all !

Thanks

Comment: Have a look here: https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc you should be able to handle exceptions, instead to avoid it.

Comment: Yeah create @ControllerAdvice would be your solutoin I htink

Answer (score 0):

***First approach:***

One if the solutions are to use the `@ExceptionHandler` annotation.

**For example:**

```
@PostMapping("/")
public String doSomething(  ) 
{   
    Foo bar = new Foo();
    bar.doSomething();
    throw new RuntimeException("Hello Exception");
    return "/Complete";
}

@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public String doSomething( String error ) 
{   
    // Handle error here and return error view..
    return "error_view";
}
```

In the example above each time an exception will be thrown from the controller scope which holds the `@ExceptionHandler` handler, this handler will be invoked, and using it you can decide which view will be rendered.

**This solution is limited to one controller scope**, the one that holds `@ExceptionHandler` handler.

***Second approach:***

Using a global handler exception resolver, you'll need to add a class that implements the `HandlerExceptionResolver` interface.

**for example:**

```
@Component
public class GlobalHandlerExceptionResolver implements HandlerExceptionResolver {

    @Override
    public ModelAndView resolveException(
        HttpServletRequest request, 
        HttpServletResponse response, 
        Object handler,
        Exception exception
    ) {
        // return here your global exception view
        return null;
    }

}
```

It is important to mark that handler as a Spring Bean

***Third approach:***

To use controller advice, However, i believe that the second approach is more what you're looking for.